# Change the style of MenuItem on android toolbar

Tags: android, menu, styles, toolbar, gravity

I'm using android `toolbar` for my application `actionbar`.
It has an action button which has 2 `MenuItems` like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to change the style of the `MenuItems` to represent something like the following:

[image]

But I can only change the textColor and font by using this style as my toolbar's theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">

    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>

</style>
```

How can I change the gravity of the text to stick to the end of the line ?

I tried these on my style and no success:

```
<item name="android:gravity">end</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">end</item>
<item name="android:gravity">right</item>
<item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
```